# how to create a google calc file with pandas dataframe on each sheet

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I am trying to use the google sheet api to create a file containing on each sheet a dataframe.

The code is failing and I do not know how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe


    title = 'example_api'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        '/home/lpuggini/MyApps/credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)


    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


    sheet = {
        'properties': {
            'title': title
        }
    }
    sheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=sheet,
                                          fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
    print('Spreadsheet ID: {0}'.format(sheet.get('spreadsheetId')))

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])
    set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)
```

I get the following error:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Desktop$ python prova.py 
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=541601611663-74g6a9ue9e8a6ps212cfu3q6lpens1hv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirec
t_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A38071%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&state=vhowmlA2HbiOdnLjegDwjcZphneA4F&access_type=offline&code_challenge=EiewMpshQe8K-4qJmtTMyhHynmIs-wIV5
YC3BFVjXJs&code_challenge_method=S256
[27080:27099:0807/162558.128868:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 3 ms for network service
Opening in existing browser session.
Spreadsheet ID: 1qAuJf0KMl3Gsgbzu4nBBEIrd9kO0byMlCCZhndHWrOo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 29, in <module>
    set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)
  File "/home/lpuggini/VirtualEnvs/diagnosis_analysis_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread_dataframe.py", line 176, in set_with_dataframe
    _resize_to_minimum(worksheet, y, x)
  File "/home/lpuggini/VirtualEnvs/diagnosis_analysis_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread_dataframe.py", line 68, in _resize_to_minimum
    worksheet.col_count,
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'col_count'
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Desktop$
```

I think I am not using the api properly but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet and put the values of dataframe.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with Python.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that the reason of your issue is `sheet` of `sheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=sheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()` cannot be used for `sheet` of `set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)`.

I would like to propose 2 patterns. Please think of this as one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used with google-api-python-client. The new Spreadsheet is created using the method of spreadsheets.create, and the values are put to the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.values.update.

#### Modified script:

```
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe

title = 'example_api'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    '/home/lpuggini/MyApps/credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Create new Spreadsheet.
sheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': title
    }
}
sheet = service.spreadsheets().create(
    body=sheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])
value_range_body = {
    'values': df.values.tolist()
}

# Put values to the created Spreadsheet.
res = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=sheet['spreadsheetId'], range="A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body=value_range_body).execute()
print(res)
```

- If an error occurs at `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)`, please modify to `creds = flow.run_local_server()`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, gspread and gspread_dataframe are used. If you use gspread, the script is as follows. About `credentials`, please check [the document](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Create new Spreadsheet.
sh = client.create('sample title')
sheet = sh.sheet1

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])

# Put values to the created Spreadsheet.
set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)
```

### Note:

- In above scripts, it supposes that Sheets API can be used. If you want to know how to use Sheets API, for example, I think that this official site is useful. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.